# ansible - Run "command db2 update database manager configuration using svcename db2c_db2inst1" as db2 user

Tags: automation, db2

I am setting up ansible to install a DB2 on a linux server. Everything is working except in the last step I need to run:

```
db2 update database manager configuration using svcename db2c_db2inst1
```

However, I cannot seem to run that as a unprivileged user (I can run it as db2isnt1 user from cmd line and it works). The task I am using looks like this:

```
  tasks:
    - name: setup svcename db2c_db2inst1
      remote_user: db2inst1
      shell: db2 update database manager configuration using svcename db2c_db2inst1
```

but I get the following error:

> TASK [setup svcename db2c_db2inst1]
>   ******************************************** fatal: [db2ansible]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "db2 update database manager
>   configuration using svcename db2c_db2inst1", "delta":
>   "0:00:00.003631", "end": "2017-02-13 16:39:38.301753", "failed": true,
>   "rc": 127, "start": "2017-02-13 16:39:38.298122", "stderr": "/bin/sh:
>   1: db2: not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Warren.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your last task like this:

```
tasks:
    - name: setup svcename db2c_db2inst1
      shell: db2 update database manager configuration using svcename db2c_db2inst1
      become: yes
      become_user: db2inst1
```

This will really execute the `db2` command with db2inst1 user, which has the `db2` executable in it's `$PATH`

Comment: If I run it as you suggested I get prompted for 2 passwords, the first one is ssh password and the second one sudo password. I get errors if I enter the passwords correctly and if I enter the db2inst1 password both times.

Comment: @warhansen You really shouldn't be using password-enabled SSH. Use keys.

Comment: I have a ssh authorized_keys to log in but the still does not allow me to run commands on Ubuntu like it does on centos

Comment: You're confusing two things: ssh authentication and sudo. Ensure configuration parity between CentOS and Ubuntu and you won't have this issue.

Comment: The sftp subsystems in ubuntu and centos are different I think, so he has to watch for that - they are in different locations.

Comment: Hi, 

So I got the command using:

    - name: setup svcename db2c_db2inst1
      shell: sudo -H -u db2inst1 bash -c '/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2 update database manager configuration using svcename db2c_db2inst1'$

logging in as a sudoer user. So basically logging in as a sudo user and running a command from there as different user. A bit of a workaround but it works.

Comment: Instead of `sudo..` in the shell module you should youse `become:  yes`. People have created modules and features for us - use them.

Answer (score 1):

Give the full path to your `db2` binary.

Comment: This seems to make sense: I tried:   tasks:
    - name: setup svcename db2c_db2inst1
      shell: /home/db2inst1/sqllib update database manager configuration using svcename db2c_db2inst1
      remote_user: db2inst1 ------- Now I get permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You would must load "`db2profile`" previously:

```
tasks:
  - name: setup svcename db2c_db2inst1
    shell: "$INSTANCEPATH/sqllib/db2profile; db2 update database manager configuration using svcename db2c_db2inst1"
    become: yes
    become_user: db2inst1
```

When `$INSTANCEPATH` is the path's home of db2 instance (e.g., `/home/db2inst1`)